# Why setViewValue() is not updating values on all places in this case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content </div>
        <input test type="text" ng-model="name" >
        <h1>name: {{name}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

`app.js` is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, controller) {
            if (!controller) {
                console.log("controller of ngModel not found");
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("controller of ngModel found");
                controller.$setViewValue('qwerty');
            }
        }
    };
});
```

In above example in the `link` function I am accessing `controller` of `ngModel` directive by using `require` option specified in `DDO`. And then using that object I am updating value of `name` and this gets updated `<h1>name: {{name}}</h1>` inside of `index.html` but not in `<input test type="text" ng-model="name">` also inside of `index.html`. Why it's updated in one place but not on the other?

> Code @ [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/BNay3sldZYDujDfNKnLj?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

From angular-source:

> It's also important to note that `$setViewValue` does not call
>   `$render` or change the control's DOM value in any way. If we want to
>   change the control's DOM value programmatically, we should update the
>   `ngModel` scope expression.

In this example you can: `$parse($attr.ngModel).assign($scope, 'qwerty')`

Answer (score 1):

$setViewValue will not update the $modelValue directly, you need to fire the `$render()` function on `ngModel` controller, that will pass that `$viewValue` to `$modelValue` & accordingly you will get the binding working on the page.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, controller) {
            if (!controller) {
                console.log("controller of ngModel not found");
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("controller of ngModel found");
                controller.$setViewValue('qwerty');
                controller.$render(); //to update $modelValue
            }
        }
    };
});
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bV34gbMiv9m6PQTWO4rT?p=preview)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change the model value directly and let angular handle running the `model -> view` pipeline, render, etc?